# Double query in one html table [PHP/mysql]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Guys I have something like this to put the results in html table. Code looks as follow:

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'username'; // Username
$db_pass = 'password'; // Password
$db_name = 'database'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = "select * FROM Table WHERE test ='10'";  
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}


?>
        <table id="MyTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
        <br><br>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NO</th>
                <th><?=$this->lang->line('NO');?> [h]</th>
                <th><?=$this->lang->line('RESULTS1');?></th>
                <th><?=$this->lang->line('RESULTS2');?></th>
                <th><?=$this->lang->line('RESULTS3');?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $no     = 0;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $amount  = $row['time_spent'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['result1'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['result2'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['result3'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['reg_date'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['result from another ($sql)'].'</td>
                </tr>';
            $total += $row['result1'];

            $no++;
        }?>
        </tbody>
        </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><?=$this->lang->line('application_total');?></td>
                <th><? echo $total_time;?></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Everything is fine but is there any possible to add to this code a second sql query, so that I would put the results to some `<td>...</td>` in the same table as shown above?

Comment: What is the second query be used for? You can either use a mysql JOIN to get related data from another table or do a 2nd query and use PHP to concatenate the results together before inserting them into the table.

Comment: select id from table where test ='10'

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is fine but is there any possible to add to this code a
>   second sql query..

of course it is possible.

you can do like "select * FROM another_Table WHERE the_id ='". $row["relation_id"] ."'";

but if the relation is 1-1, than i recommend you to use the join table instead of executing a new query.

ie:

```
select a.*, b.another_field 
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.relation_id = a.relation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it is not wise to nest a query in a loop.simply because the nested query will be executed every time.That a bad code style.
2. You had better to obtain a result once by `join` or `constraint`